# Graph Sensor Data with Python and Matplotlib real time

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to plot a graph using matplotlib. I am sensing data from sensor and putting that data into excel file. but I am not able to get desired output.

i am attaching the [sample code](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/graph-sensor-data-with-python-and-matplotlib/update-a-graph-in-real-time) link here.

Also I am attaching my code which I modified. can anyone help in this matter

```
    import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import xlrd

hsif = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\Hp\\Desktop\\Sensor.xlsx','Sheet2', skiprows=3)

data = hsif.columns.values[3]
print(data)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
xs = []
ys = []


# This function is called periodically from FuncAnimation
def animate(i, xs, ys):

    # Read data from sensor
    temp_c = data

    # Add x and y to lists
    xs.append(dt.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M '))
    ys.append(temp_c) 

    # Limit x and y lists to 20 items
    xs = xs[-20:]
    ys = ys[-20:]

    # Draw x and y lists
    ax.clear()
    ax.plot(xs, ys)

    # Format plot
    plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')
    plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.30)
    plt.title('Call OI over Time')
    plt.ylabel('Numbers')

# Set up plot to call animate() function periodically
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, fargs=(xs, ys), interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answer is sufficient. :S that last one got deleted pretty quick lol

so i cant offer code for your situation, but i can help point you in the right direction..
I was able to achieve a live graph from sensor readings every second by doing the following

get the date and time with

```
timeObj = time.localtime(Epoch)
thedate = '%d-%d-%d' % (timeObj.tm_mon, timeObj.tm_mday, timeObj.tm_year)
thetime = '%d:%d:%d' % (timeObj.tm_hour, timeObj.tm_min, timeObj.tm_sec)
```

you could combine date and time into a single string, but i don't use date on my graphs. I wanted them in separate lists. Then, in your animate function, which is called every second. youre going to want to add a dataframe. I used pandas to open a csv (sorry i dont have experience opening excel), which automatically makes a dataframe when opened like so: (dateparse makes the time readable by matplotlib)

```
dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '$H:$M:$S')
def animate(e):
    headers = ['date', 'time', 'sensor']
    SonarDataF = pd.read_csv('livegraph.csv', parse_dates=True, date_parser=dateparse, names=headers, skiprows=1)
```

then in the next lines of animate call a function to add the time and reading into the dataframe.

```
new_row = {'date': thedate, 'time': thetime, 'sensor': distance} 
SonarDataF = SonarDataF.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
```

your next few lines will check your data, once it gets to 20 rows, it deletes 1 row with every entry, which happens every 1000ms based on animation

```
num_rows = SonarDataF.shape[0]  # limits rows allowed in graph csv
if num_rows > 20:
    SonarDataF = SonarDataF.iloc[1:]
```

and now you have to save your new data readings pulled with the animate function into your csv (or excel, youll have to look up how to do that)
I save to 2 different files. 1 has 20 lines for the graph. and 1 is a log with every reading ever taken. if you want to go back and check readings from previous times you can open the second file and choose what to plot

```
SonarDataF.to_csv('livegraph.csv', index=False)  # saves updated dataframe to be reloaded on next animate
lognumbers = {'date': thedate, 'time': thetime, 'sensor': sensor}  # saves new time and reading to full log
csv_file = "LogData.csv"
try:
    with open(csv_file, 'a') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=headers)
        for data in lognumbers:
            writer.writerow(lognumbers)
except IOError:
    print('fuck')
# get time, and convert it for matplotlib
tim3 = SonarDataF['time']
rTime = [datetime.strptime(t, '%H:%M:%S') for t in tim3]
rSensor = SonarDataF['sensor'].astype(float)
a.clear()
a.plot(rTime,rSensor)
```

if you'd like to see my code that i pulled these examples from, see my question which has a working example of grabbing data from a sensor
[pi4 GUI + matplotlib: Reading sensor, read/write csv, and updating matplotlib with static labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64019163/pi4-gui-matplotlib-reading-sensor-read-write-csv-and-updating-matplotlib-wi)

Comment: Thanks for your inputs it is really helpful. But my same code can do the work if I use spyder notebook. I was faced another problem, my code only work if excel file will save automatically on every changing value. here I am stuck.

Comment: your python code doesnt have any lines in it to read a sensor.
its just reading a file, so unless that file is constantly being updated by another program. you will have a hard time getting it to do what you want.

Comment: or you could try putting your pd.open and data line into the animate function and see if it autoupdates the list.